# (Expression) Bag of bones / Sack of bones / Bones sack

Tags: word-usage, expressions

Are all of these expressions correct ? For rhyming purposes I was planning to use the third one, but I'm not sure it is correct because I've never seen that formulation :

> 1 - Bag of bones
>
> 2 - Sack of bones
>
> 3 - Bones sack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain phrases are **fixed phrases;** this particularly applies to idioms. A person is not *actually* a bag containing bones; he's a person, even if he's extremely thin.

The idiom is usually *bag of bones* (at least in British English).

There is an additional issue with *bones sack* — *bones* here is an attributive noun, a noun which functions like an adjective, describing the purpose of the sack. But adjectives in English are never inflected for number, and this includes attributive nouns. The expression must be *bone sack.* However, that’s ambiguous, as it could be referring [however improbably] to a sack made of bone. The way around that difficulty is to hyphenate it as *bone-sack*.

Comment: I don't know about that, one hears "drugs gangs" or similar etc. on the BBC. In fact, it is the AmE speakers who never use a plural noun adjectivally. I can't think of other examples right now but I do hear them on BBC Radio. And  would advise again bone-sack here.